# Why is $\mathbb{C}$ a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ but $\mathbb{R}$ not a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

My book (Álgebra Linear by Isabel Cabral, Cecilia Perdigao and Carlos Saiago) asks the question in the title but doesn't offer solutions. My guess is that the elements of $\mathbb{R}$ are in $\mathbb{C}$  but not all the elements of $\mathbb{C}$ are in $\mathbb{R}$, so you can't do any operations on it, and a vector space is defined by a set and operations on that set? Would this set have "gaps" or would it be empty, because every element of $\mathbb{C}$ can be represented as $a+bi$ and $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't have complex numbers?

Comment: What is the action of $\mathbb{C}$ on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @anomaly Multiplication and addition?

Comment: +1 This is a nice question - can you add the name of the book you are referring to the body of the question?

Comment: @Brahadeesh It's a portuguese one... Álgebra Linear by Isabel Cabral, Cecilia Perdigao and Carlos Saiago

Comment: Ims, Halmos considers $\Bbb R$ as a vector space over $\Bbb C$ in _Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces_.

Comment: See @Chris Eagle and Arturo Magidin's answers here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/154883

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to define in $\mathbb{R}$ a structure of $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, you must define an operation (called scalar multiplication)
$$(-*-)\colon\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
$$(z,v)\mapsto z*v$$
But the obvious operation (i.e, the product in $\mathbb{C}$) doesn't work, as you said, because $zv$ does not have to be in $\mathbb{R}.$

You can prove that in fact you can't define any operation which respects the conditions of vector space that induces the usual multiplication when restricted to $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}:$

Let's say that if $z\in\mathbb{R}$ then $z*v=zv$, the usual multiplication in $\mathbb{R}.$ Then $(-*-)$ is determined by $(\textbf{i}*1)$, because every $z\in\mathbb{C}$ can be written as $a+b\textbf{i},\ a,b\in\mathbb{R},$
so for every $v\in\mathbb{R}$ $$(a+b\textbf{i})*v=a*v+b\textbf{i}*v=av+bv(\textbf{i}*1)$$
(I'm using here the distributive property of a vector space). But, if $(\textbf{i}*1)=a,$ then $(a-\textbf{i})*1=a*1-\textbf{i}*1=a-a=0$, which is a contradiction since $a\neq\textbf{i}$ and $ 1\neq 0$.

Comment: +1 Good answer.

Comment: @Brahadeesh Thank you, and thank you for the correction!

Comment: It's a good answer, but I think you should emphasise the assumption in your third paragraph, since that's the key point. Without it there are lots of ways of making $\mathbb{R}$ into a $\mathbb{C}$ vector space.

Comment: Could you explain that in beginner friendly terms?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire Well, the point is that you actually can make $\mathbb{R}$ a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, but you can't do that in a way that the operation you define is the usual multiplication when restricted to $\mathbb{R}. $ That's what I prove above. Define $z*v$ to be the usual multiplication when $z$ is a real number, now you must define how it acts on any complex number, but I conclude that there is no operation $(-*-)\colon\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that can induce that, because you get to a contradiction.